# Row index from indexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios

I often call a web service when a view loads and save an NSMutableArray with the contents of the call. Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath I retrieve the rows from this array. I use what feels like a hack to get the row index from the indexPath, however:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    <snip cell alloc stuff>

    // Configure the cell.
    unsigned int *indexes = (unsigned int*)calloc( [indexPath length], sizeof( unsigned int ) );
    [indexPath getIndexes:indexes];
    Tasks *task = [_tasksArray objectAtIndex:indexes[1]];   
    free( indexes );

    cell.textLabel.text = [task getname];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Started: %@", [task getstarted] ? [[task getstarted] description] : @"Not Yet"];

    return cell;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to access the row part of the indexPath

```
indexPath.row
```

Here's a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2) to Apple's documentation for [NSIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2).

Comment: Cool, thanks. I knew it should be that easy but got caught up reading about the internals of NSIndexPath and didn't see the property.

Comment: The Documentation shows NSIndexPath Class Reference as the first hit if you search for NSIndexPath, which is in fact misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `row` property from [NSIndexPath UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html).